# I can only receive one word (winsock c++ tcp/ip server and client)

Tags: c++, networking, winsock, winsock2

I managed to create a tcp server and client with winsock in c++ but for a reason that is unknown to me I can not send more than one word at a time.

see by yourself:

[image: snapshot]

I specify that I am an absolute beginner and that my code probably contains errors so do not hesitate to correct me if you find some. (also english isn't my first language so sorry for the spelling mistake).

I ask for help because I just spent several hours looking for a solution to my problem without finding it. I think I missed part of my code but I do not know where and why. I looked at the server and client source code created by other people but I do not find how my own is different. (I am sorry if I did a very simple mistake)

client.cpp

```
    #define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <iostream>
    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdio.h>

    #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "--- Chat Section ---" << std::endl;

        WSADATA wsa;
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
        sockaddr_in dest;
        dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
        dest.sin_port = htons(8888);
        dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        SOCKET client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        connect(client, (sockaddr*)& dest, sizeof(dest));

        std::string ok;
        char buf[512];
        do
        {

            std::cin >> ok;
            if (ok.size() > 0)
            {
                send(client, ok.c_str(), ok.length(), 0);
                ZeroMemory(&buf, sizeof(buf));
                int okok = recv(client, buf, 512, 0);
                if (okok > 0)
                {
                    std::string str(buf);
                    std::cout <<">> "<< str << std::endl;
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                    // std::cout << std::string(buf, 0, okok) << std::endl;
                }
            }
        } while (true);

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Server tcp/ip test V.14.0" << std::endl;

    WSADATA wsa;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    sockaddr_in server, client;

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);
    // bind
    bind(s, (sockaddr*)& server, sizeof(server));
    //listen
    listen(s, 3);
    //Accept
    sockaddr_in from; // for the client
    int fromlen = sizeof(from);
    SOCKET clientS = accept(s, (sockaddr*)& from, &fromlen);
    if (clientS == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "error with accept()" << std::endl;
    }


    char recvbuf[512];


    do
    {
        int iResult = recv(clientS, recvbuf, 512, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            send(clientS, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
        }



    } while(true);



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::cin >> ok` stops reading at the first whitespace. You may be looking for `std::getline`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What's wrong with std::cin ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `std::cin`. It's the `>>`. It doesn't do what you think it does. For more information, see your C++ book.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll go read about this.

Comment: You send one word at a time as opposed to what? What kind of thing do you want to send one at a time?

Comment: @MatGeneral That's just how `cin >> string` works. Not broken, just how they designed it.

Comment: How weird: You managed to get the TCP/IP communication working but failed to use the standard input correctly? (In my case, it was vice versa as far as I remember...) ;-)